# Deleted users show up differently in a list in the timeline

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, timeline

If a question is closed (or reopened) then the list of close (or reopen) voters is displayed in the timeline of that question, with each username on a new line. For instance:

> [image: list of reopen voters, each on a new line]

*The above image shows the following list:*

> Brahadeesh
>   user729424
>   Batominovski
>   Eric Wofsey
>   Matt Samuel

However, if one of the users has deleted their account, then their generic username is displayed on the same line as the next voter, with a comma separating the two entries. For instance:

> [image: list of reopen voters, not all on a new line]

*The above image shows the following list:*

> Gone
>   user170039, Brahadeesh
>   Zacky
>   John Omielan

Here, user170039 is the deleted user.

---

Can the timeline be modified so that the lists are always displayed consistently? I encountered the differences at Mathematics Meta SE, but I presume the timeline is displayed the same way everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We have one function which takes a list of user votes attached in a post history and converts that to a list of user links.  This is used not just in post timelines but in things like showing the list of users who have closed or deleted a post.

This is the only case where we have the users listed one per line instead of separated by commas and this was implemented with a very old hack of just replacing `,`  with `<br/>` via JavaScript.  This hack had to be refined when we rolled out the dupe hammer, since it contained additional commas, so we started replacing `</a>,`  with `</a><br/>` and `</span>,`  with `</span><br>`.  This again used JavaScript on page load.

Unfortunately, deleted users don't have links and are showed up in the list as `user####,` , which didn't match the expression and therefore were left with commas instead of line breaks.

My solution was to get rid of the hack and pass a parameter to the original link rendering function saying so it would render `<br>` instead of `,`  in the timeline.