# All post history events are now incorrectly showing as edits in post histories and timelines

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, revisions-list, timeline

When checking the timeline of a post I noticed that "Post Closed" events are now attributed to Community, and the close voters were moved to the "comment" column. Before, all close voters were listed in the "by" column. The same happened for "Post Reopened".

However, the event was also turned into an "edited" event, with Community adding all the post content, which is a bit confusing.

---

**Before** (screenshot borrowed from [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347531/deleted-users-show-up-differently-in-a-list-in-the-timeline)):

> [image: "Reopened" timeline entry, voters listed in "by" column]

**Now** ([question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12852508/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries)):

> [image]

Comment: We figured it out, we think. Turns out that one can break a whole lot of stuff with one little `!=` instead of `==`. We won't be able to push this tonight because we need to make sure that fixing this doesn't have unintended consequences elsewhere, but we'll be able to get it fixed ASAP tomorrow. Thank you so much for reporting this bug.

Comment: To steal an old joke: "Cost of changing `!=` to `==`: $1.00. Cost of knowing which `!=` to change: $999.00."

Comment: @kristinalustig: Did you add some kind of regression test for this (or for some larger scope - covering more than the very specific)?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q That's up next!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has been fixed!

This took a while to triage because it touched a ton of different functions I wasn't used to poking around in, including the post history and post history revision generation.

### The Bug

The source of the problem was a function that checked if the post history entry had any content changes. This is a function that effectively hasn't been touched since Atwood first committed it 12 years ago. The original function was:

```cs
public bool HasContent()
{
    return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tags) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Body));
}
```

This function was then modified to add a new component involving checking for some new feature that we haven't shipped. It looked similar to this:

```cs
public bool HasContent()
{
    return !(NewFeature != NewFeature.None && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tags) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Body));
}
```

This function is kinda hard to read though - applying [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) we can negate the entire statement to make it a little more readable:

```cs
public bool HasContent()
{
    return NewFeature == NewFeature.None || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Tags) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Title) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Body);
}
```

The bug here is now pretty clear - we consider anything that has the new feature set to none as having its content changed. Because `NewFeature` was an `enum`, we have the behavior of `default(NewFeature) == 0 == NewFeature.None`, which meant that *all* post history items had this value set to `NewFeature.None`. This meant that all post history items were now considered to have content.

There's a function that transforms the list of post history entries to revision entries, and it depended on this check. With this buggy behavior, it started doing unpredictable things like displaying extra revisions for reopens or showing weird things in the post's timeline. *Lots* of other things depend of this content check working, so I'm certain that other features on the site were impacted too.

The approximate period of time this bug was live was:

- Start: 2021-09-14 13:50 UTC
- End: 2021-09-15 15:31 UTC

### Next Steps

- [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) I've added items on our technical debt backlog to take care of adding tests/refactoring the `HasContent` function, as well as adding tests for the dependencies of `HasContent` that were demonstrating the buggy behavior. This bug is something that automated tests can and should catch - we're just missing test coverage here.
- [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) During this buggy period, the revision counts were off. Some post history items were being counted as a revision, so this threw off anything that referenced a revision by its number. We have performed a network-wide fix of this data that [fixes rollbacks pointing at invalid revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369849/718314) (there were less than 10 instances of this across the network).

Comment: *we're just missing test coverage here.* ... if it is not too embarrassing mind giving a ballpark number where your coverage is at?

Comment: @rene No numbers to share, but it's below where we'd like it. It's a priority of the engineering group to improve how we do testing and get better code coverage. I'm personally part of our internal testing working group, running an internal engineering book club for the book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://understandlegacycode.com/blog/key-points-of-working-effectively-with-legacy-code/), and trying to add tests to any work I do here on the Public Platform team. We've got a really great velocity, but still have lots of work ahead.

Comment: As of 2021-09-15T210820Z+0, the [edit grace period is still on the order of 0 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43526808/revisions) (not 300 seconds (5 minutes)).

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to have completely screwed up revision histories on the (defunct) app, as the bug clearly took effect, but the fix hasn't

Comment: We do not have a goal of 100% test coverage, not planning on sharing any numbers related to this (when the unstated judgment is that of your are below 100%, you still have more to do).

Comment: Looks like this same bug [has cropped up again for the API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370743/revision-number-is-returned-in-every-revision-item-even-if-its-not-an-edit).

Answer (score 16):

This bug seems to be much wider in scope, affecting actual site functionality, and not only display.

Not only closing events are affected, but other events (locking, deleting, etc.) are also affected.

See the below screenshot of a question's revision history:

[image: All post modified events show as edits]

When actions by multiple people take place, the "edit" is attributed to the Community user. When a binding action takes place, the "edit" is attributed to whoever took the action.

Also, <s>**I'm unable to rollback to prior revisions from before a closing/reopening, (un)deleting, or (un)locking action took place** - clicking the Rollback button on such a prior revision produces an error message "Unable to rollback".</s> (It turns out I wasn't reproducing this correctly - I *was* able to rollback to a prior revision, just not those that happen to contain the same content or are the current revision with text.)

Finally, this bug **breaks links to specific revisions** on posts - as the revision numbers are changed, and the URLs only contain the revision number and not the ID, a link to, say, revision 5 which took place after a history event, will link to the wrong revision, as that revision is now numbered 6.

Comment: Do you happen to have the exact text of the error message that you got when you tried to roll something back? We're digging into this bug right now and having the exact text would help us narrow it down. Thank you!

Comment: @kristinalustig Seems I was kind of wrong. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17016/whats-the-best-way-to-contribute-to-stack-overflow-if-you-dont-have-a-ton-of-t) is the question highlighted here. Attempting to rollback to revision 3 (with the current text) produces an error message "Unable to rollback to the current revision". Attempting it on revision 2 or any revision 4+ produces an error message "Unable to rollback because the revisions are identical." Rolling back to revision 1 worked, resulting in revision 11, and I self-reverted that rollback.

Comment: Copying from above: we figured it out, we think. Turns out that one can break a whole lot of stuff with one little `!=` instead of `==`. We won't be able to push this tonight because we need to make sure that fixing this doesn't have unintended consequences elsewhere, but we'll be able to get it fixed ASAP tomorrow.

Comment: As of 2021-09-15T151245Z+0, the edit grace period is 0 seconds, at least on Stack Overflow main (but does require a change to the content (that functionality didn't change)).

Comment: @kristinalustig It seems that the fix for this bug (deployed recently) broke the edit summary for the last rollback I performed on that post. It shows as "Rollback to Revision 0"; it should show as "Rollback to Revision 4".

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog we're just discussing that now - the buggy behavior meant that all of the revision counts were off as the reopen/close entries were being shown as revisions. Just about to post an answer with some more context.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog We've got a good understanding of what's broken here - it looks like your revision from the question you linked was a rollback to the Post Closed history item, which was a revision during the buggy period, but is no longer a revision after we fixed the bug. Thankfully we're referencing history item GUIDs and not the specific revision number in our database entries here, so we may be able to fix the data on any history items pointing at non-existent revisions during this period.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog After some investigation, we're not planning on tackling the last bug in your post right now, but we might come back to it in the future. [See my answer for more details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369886/718314).

Comment: @KylePollard It seems the fix for this bug caused another bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369891/editing-an-earlier-revision-of-a-post-doesnt-change-it-nor-does-it-create-a-new

Comment: The data in Post Histories affected by this has been fixed.