# Did the "grace period" for edits on posts break?

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, revisions-list, grace-period

Did the grace period for edits on posts recently go away? Or did the mechanism break maybe?

---

I was recently editing an FAQ post on MSO, and after saving the edit, realized I changed something which I didn't intend to.

No problem, I noticed this well within the 5 minute grace period window; I edited again to fix the mistake. The edit summary from the previous edit appeared in the edit summary input below the post, I made my change and submitted it.

I checked [the revision history of the post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/288506/revisions) later, and noticed that **my grace period edit had been logged as a separate edit**, with the same edit summary as my prior edit.

No comments had been made on the post since the first edit, and none of the [other criteria for invalidating the grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216567/reset-question-grace-period-once-an-answer-has-been-posted/251876#251876) appeared to apply.

For science, I tested this on a post of mine in the sandbox (all CW posts), and [was able to replicate the behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/369341/revisions). I <del>wasn't able to replicate this on a non-CW post</del> was recently [able to replicate this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69091112/revisions) proper as well (first edit, non-CW post).

Here's another case from [@bobble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1017231/bobble) on [a non-CW post here on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/191773/revisions).

Did the editing grace period on posts break? Was it turned off intentionally?

This appears *not* to have the same underlying cause as this [bug](/questions/tagged/bug): [All post history events are now incorrectly showing as edits in post histories and timelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/all-post-history-events-are-now-incorrectly-showing-as-edits-in-post-histories-a) after all, since that was officially fixed, but I'm still [able to repro](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/369341/revisions) this on my sandbox post.

Comment: The same thing happened to me when I was improving a suggested edit from the review queue: https://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/183735/revisions It kept the comment, so I thought there would be one revision, but nope.

Comment: My guess is that it's related to this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369846/334566

Comment: @PM2Ring true, as the developer mentioned in a comment, the bug has wider scope than reported there and it broke many things.

Comment: @PM2Ring That was a great guess, but it appears this is not the case; the other bug is marked as complete and [was deployed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369891/editing-an-earlier-revision-of-a-post-doesnt-change-it-nor-does-it-create-a-new#comment1234518_369891), but I'm still able to repro this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This bug was related to [the bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/all-post-history-events-are-now-incorrectly-showing-as-edits-in-post-histories-a) that we fixed yesterday. We got the grace period fixed this evening (and actually, the fix for [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369891/editing-an-earlier-revision-of-a-post-doesnt-change-it-nor-does-it-create-a-new/369897#369897) was the same as the fix for this one). It should be live soon (within a half hour or so). Thank you so much for reporting it.