# Editing an earlier revision of a post doesn't change it nor does it create a new revision item, but shows me as the last editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, revisions-list

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a post that has been edited at least once.
2. Go to the revisions history
3. Click 'Edit' on an earlier revision:

   [image]
4. Do not edit the body, just add a random edit summary.
5. Submit your edits.

Now you're one of the post editors, however, your name doesn't show in its revision history nor is the edit registered under "posts edited" in your profile! The problem is, I haven't managed to reproduce the bug in [some](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69183661/revisions) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69188308/revisions), while in others, [I](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57150191) [have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61085960).

What's going on?

Comment: I think this should be fixed, given that this is the [officially documented way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41954/377214) to specify a reason for a rollback.

Comment: That other post was mistagged, I forgot to update the tags. Fix had been deployed since 2021-09-15 15:31Z, approximately three hours ago. It's unclear to me that the fix deployed three hours ago would have caused this issue - this may have been another problem caused by the original change that caused the bug yesterday?

Comment: @double-beep Just to confirm - were all four of the posts you referenced done using the reproduction steps in your post, or is there a chance some were done with the `Rollback` button?

Comment: @KylePollard I reproduced this on a [CW answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368986/818993), but I did the "common edit flow": 1. Find the answer; 2. Click edit; 3. Click "Save edits" (without changing anything, nor adding a summary). The question in home page [shows that I modified something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ECPl.png)

Comment: @KylePollard nope, 2 other users (including me) participated in the experiment. Consistently reproduceable - steps taken have been identical. As a tangential observation, those edits [do not show up](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids#ids=61085960&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) in the API so it appears as if they are never submitted in the first place

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This bug was indeed related to the [bug that we fixed yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/all-post-history-events-are-now-incorrectly-showing-as-edits-in-post-histories-a) - it's not that our bug broke other things, but that our fix didn't catch everything affected. We're getting a fix out tonight. Thank you so much for reporting. We did a quick check and it looks like rollbacks on approximately 64 posts across all of Stack Exchange were affected over the past couple of days.