# Why is the "Became Hot Network Question" event shown as an edit?

Tags: bug, edits, hot-questions, revisions-list, timeline

I was looking at [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168430/105447) to see when it became a Hot Network Question. I went to the [revisions page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/168430/revisions) and noticed that this event is shown as an edit, along with the tweet on Twitter:

> [image]

The timeline [also shows this as an edit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/168430/timeline#history_887a80d9-d4e2-4a00-895c-b95c32747802). Is this intentional?

Comment: I think this probably a dupicate of [this general history brokenness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369846/all-post-history-events-are-now-incorrectly-showing-as-edits-in-post-histories-a)

Comment: It's now fixed.